# How to corectly set the date time before importing CSV to PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, formatting, sqldatatypes

I'm creating the table:

```
CREATE TABLE application
(
    application_id INT,                             
    client_id INT,                                  
    application_date_created DATE,
    decision VARCHAR(10),                               
    limit_ FLOAT                                        
)
```

Later I'm importing a `.CSV` like this:

```
COPY application FROM 'blablabla' DELIMITER ';' CSV HEADER;
```

But the problem is that the 'application_date_created' format is 'dd.mm.yyyy', so I get an error

> ERROR: date/time field value out of range: "16.03.2021"

How do I set the right format before importing that `.CSV` file?

I hope anyone can help me

Comment: _"8.5.1. Date/Time Input
Date and time input is accepted in almost any reasonable format, including ISO 8601, SQL-compatible, traditional POSTGRES, and others. For some formats, ordering of day, month, and year in date input is ambiguous and there is support for specifying the expected ordering of these fields. Set the DateStyle parameter to MDY to select month-day-year interpretation, DMY to select day-month-year interpretation, or YMD to select year-month-day interpretation."_ See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html

Answer (score 0):

`set datestyle = 'iso,dmy';`

then

`select '16.03.2021'::date; 2021-03-16`

will work.

After do

`set datestyle = default;`

to get back to your default.

See [Date/time input](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-INPUT) and [Date/time output](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-OUTPUT) for more information.